# Writing to a file with bach

Tags: windows

Is there a way to use bach to write to an admin file? In Linux I know how to do this but can bach echo do this?

I need to add a line to the hosts file under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you're going to need to do is use the > symbol.  If you use it twice as I have below it will append to a file, if you use it once it will overwrite. Since you're saying it is an admin file you may need to run your .bat file with elevated privileges to make it work properly.

```
@echo writing this now >> yourfile.text
```

Hope this helps, please let me know if I can assist farther.